# How to disable ALLOWED_HOST check on paticular Django REST API URL?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

IS there any way to disable DJANGO ALLOWED_HOST check on particular API URL,
We want to allow API requests from list of websites(HOSTS), but there is RFID reader machine which will also be writing data on our DJANGO server using REST API and we want to make only that particular REST API URL public and other REST APIs should be allowed as ALLOWED_HOST check of DJANGO.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django REST API set allowed hosts for individual endpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68576746/django-rest-api-set-allowed-hosts-for-individual-endpoints)